# How to spy on individual functions that are default exports

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I am trying to spy on a function that is used by the function I am actually testing, so the structure is a bit like this:

```js
const trueOrFalse = (args) => {
  return true // or false;
}

export default TrueOrFalse;
```

and the function I want to import it into does

```js
import trueOrFalse from './trueOrFalse';

const myFunc = () => {
  const successful = trueOrFalse();
  if (!successful) return;
  // Otherwise do something else
}
```

For my test now I need my `trueOrFalse()` to always return `false` for example. If this was exported differently I'd be able to use `jest.spyOn` like this:

```js
  jest.spyOn(utils, 'trueOrFalse').mockImplementation(() => false);
```

But with this being a default export I can't do this, can I?

```js
  jest.spyOn(???, 'trueOrFalse').mockImplementation(() => false);
```

How can I spy on or mock this dependent function?

Comment: `jest.mock("path/to/trueOrFalse")`?

Comment: That's what I thought, but 
`beforeEach(() => { jest.mock('../trueOrFalse', () => false); });`
does not work, it still calls the real function and gives me an error.

Comment: *What* error? 1. Doesn't `jest.mock` need to be in global scope so it can get hoisted? 2. Read https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options, the bit starting *"When using the `factory` parameter for an ES6 module with a default export"*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe It can be used in test scope as well but requires a module to be re-imported locally with `jest.resetModules()` and `require`, which is likely not what the OP really needs.

Comment: Thanks, that actually solved my problem! I wasn't aware that jest.mock needs to be called outside of my actual test.

Answer (score 1):

It may be possible to spy or mock functions on module object:

```
import * as trueOrFalseMod from './trueOrFalse';

...

jest.spyOn(trueOrFalseMod, 'default');
```

This works because ES imports always refer to object properties after import internally. This may not work if module object is read-only according to ES module specs, this depends on specific Jest setup.

Otherwise a module needs to be mocked:

```
import trueOrFalse from './trueOrFalse';

jest.mock('./trueOrFalse');
```

This should result in `trueOrFalse` being a stub which implementation can be changed depending on a test:

```
trueOrFalse.mockReturnValue(false);
```